# I have problems with building my ui in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, panel, frame

i want to have an JFrame and add a JPanel "mainPanel" on it which has the same size as the JFrame and then i want to add another JPanel "gamePanel" on the mainPanel which is an GridLayout with the size 500x500 Pixels. But if i turn the color of the gamePanel blue, everything is blue.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;

public class GameViewImpl extends JFrame implements GameView {  

    JPanel mainPanel;
    JFrame mainFrame;
    JPanel gamePanel;

    @Override
    public void setController(GameController controller) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void show(int c, int r, boolean isHouse, int houseSize, int houseIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void createAndShowThread() {                 
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setSize(1000,500);
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainPanel.setSize(1000,500);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        gamePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));
        gamePanel.setSize(500,500);
        gamePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        mainPanel.add(gamePanel);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }
}
```

updated code:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    static public void main(String Args[]) {

        GameModelImpl gameModel = new GameModelImpl(10,10);
        GameViewImpl gameView = new GameViewImpl();
        GameControllerImpl gameController = new GameControllerImpl();

        gameModel.setView(gameView);
        gameView.setController(gameController);
        gameController.setModel(gameModel);
        gameView.createAndShowThread();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->gameView.createAndShowThread());
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `mainPanel` has a `BorderLayout` , `mainPanel.add(gamePanel)` will make `gamePanel` occupy the whole space of `mainPanel` (i.e it gets added with a `BorderLayout.CENTER` constraint).

Comment: What @Arnaud said. A simple FlowLayout or BoxLayout should work for this.

Comment: @ohlec it works now but the gamepanel disappears within 1s do you know an solution for that?

Comment: @paulschmitz82 that seems likea completely different problem; nothing in the code you posted here looks like it could cause something like this. Maybe you should opena new question.

Comment: @ohlec only changed the mainPanel to flowlayout and that happened

Comment: @paulschmitz82 you'll have to show more relevant code. I don't see anything that could cause this.

Comment: @ohlec i updated the code

Comment: `import javax.swing.JPanel; import javafx.scene.layout.Border;` **Don't mix Swing & Java-FX GUI elements!** Use a `javax.swing` or `java.awt` based border. Note also: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: Unless changing the border fixes the problem (it might, but can't check because there are classes missing), note: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). @ohlec *"show more relevant code"* Note that `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to the first link in this comment, and an MCVE is the best way to post code samples to SO. (There are actually two close reasons that use 'no MCVE' as part of the reason for closing!)